# Rstudio library files dumped in temp area "as ‘lib’ is unspecified"

Tags: rstudio

New to Rstudio and trying to install some packages. I've had a bit of a look on t'interweb and it suggested setting up a couple of paths - I've set up something in the windows variables too. Despite this Rstudio seems to download binaries to a temporary store.

Trying to set "lib" as a variable didn't appear to help.  Any ideas on how I set default locations for package binaries?

Many thanks

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "H:/R.Studio.Files/Rpackages"        "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library"
> R_LIBS_USER
Error: object 'R_LIBS_USER' not found
> R_LIBS_USER="H:/R.Studio.Files/Rpackages"
> R_LIBS_USER
[1] "H:/R.Studio.Files/Rpackages"
> install.packages("shiny")
Installing package into ‘H:/R.Studio.Files/Rpackages’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/shiny_1.0.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2759794 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

package ‘shiny’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\g10152\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOuR5Ly\downloaded_packages
```